# what is the difference between "manch" and "mancher" that they take different declension?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

according to this link http://www.germanveryeasy.com/adjective-declension

In the weak declension category, it says if the adjective is indicator of quantity like *mancher* then it's weak declension while *manch* is in strong category

With both have the same meaning "some" then what is the difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read carefully. The site says that weak declension is used for **declined** indicators of quantity, an example being *mancher*.
*Manch* is just not declined.

[This is](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/manch) how declination of *manch* works (from de.witkionary.org):

> ```
>            |            Singular            |  Plural
>            | Maskulinum Femininum  Neutrum  |    ——
> -----------|--------------------------------|------------
> Nominativ  | mancher    manche     manches  |  manche
> -----------|--------------------------------|------------
>            | manches               manches  |
> Genitiv    | manchen    mancher    manchen  |  mancher
> -----------|--------------------------------|------------
> Dativ      | manchem    mancher    manchem  |  manchen
> -----------|--------------------------------|------------
> Akkusativ  | manchen    manche     manches  |  manche
> ```

A more in-depth review of *manch* can also be found [at Canoo](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/InflectionRules/FRegeln-P/Pron-Indef/Pron-manch3.html?lang=en).